# This function runs fine but i would to add the functionality of withdrawing as we get only 50 100 500 notes not as randomly number (54)

Tags: python-3.x

```
def withdrawal(amount):
  amount = int(input("Withdrawal Amount : "))
  if (amount < balance):
    balance = float(balance - amount)
    print("Remaing Amount is : %.2f" %(balance))
    restart = str(input("Do you want to go back : "))                   
    if restart in ('NO','N','no','n'):
        print('Thankyou')
        exit()
```

This code work fine as it withdrawal any amount weather it 54 or 200.

Comment: If your code works fine what is your question

Answer (score 0):

The following answers your question

```
   balance = 2000.0
   def withdrawal():
       while True:
           amount = int(input("********************\nEnter one of 50,100,500 \nWithdrawal Amount : "))
           if amount in [50,100,500]:
               break
           else:
               print("{} is Invalid entry".format(amount))
       global balance
       if(amount < balance):
           balance = float(balance - amount)
           print("Remaining Amount is : %.2f" %(balance))
           restart = str(input("Do you want to go back : "))
           if restart in ('NO','N','no','n'):
               print('Thankyou')
               exit()
           else:
               withdrawal()
   withdrawal()
```

To add the condition, we took a infinite while loop and is breaking it when the amount entered is one of the 3 values.

As we are reading the value in this function, it is not required to pass as an argument. So updated the fuc definition as `def withdrawal():`

To store the initial balance value, it is initialised as 2000.0 as a global variable ouside the function and we are using it in our code with `global balance`

If the user enters Yes at the end, there is no way in your code to continue the process. So, added a call at the end to `withdrawal()`